# this device is using an alternative driver[GeForce GT 630M ]

Tags: drivers, graphics, xubuntu, xorg, nvidia-geforce

Here is the screenshot of the additional drivers:

[image: screenshot]

I want to use NVIDIA driver so that I can use tensorflow GPU version on my pc. I selected the NVIDIA driver and restarted but it is not working.

How to resolve this??

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried installing from the CLI which might give you some output. E.g `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` (change 340 to whatever version you want)

Comment: According to the [nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/95165/en-us) you need the 340 driver.

Comment: Why 340? 361 is available right?

Comment: @Programster Thanks, i just used that command! :)

Comment: @Programster here's a screenshot after running that command.
http://imgur.com/ZVX7qQL
what  does that mean? No original module exists within this kernel!

Comment: @Nuwanda the linux kernel is a "monolithic" kernel made up of various modules. By running that command you are recompiling the kernel with the relevant nvidia driver module. That message means you did not already have an nvidia module installed, which should be fine. After a reboot you should be using the nvidia driver in your kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the screen you are displaying select the topmost button.Allow a few seconds for the driver to be downloaded and installed. Reboot.